# Running Local webserver on pc or Raspberry Pi while protecting source code

Tags: php, linux, operating-system, xampp, raspberry-pi

Hello Stackoverflow community :), i really need your advice regarding this issue.

I have developed a software in php/mysql+(js/css) to help me manage my office practice.

I want to:

Setup a local server @ my office,

Problem :

I dont want anyone to get access to my php/mysql files.

can i :-

have a dedicated pc / or Raspberry pi running local server and connected to my wifi with static ip running 24/7 and yet it can automatically restart web server if power down and run server up again without need to enter password. while at same time restricting  direct access to read/copy source code files on it -incase some one tries to copy them- ?

My web application traffic is 4-5 devices @ most -tablet/pc's -, yet my application is a bit complex and run lots of data analysis and data mining and its mysql database is growing (50k+ rows in 20 tables)

**Optimum solution** i would think of is an OS including my server and all its files encrypted and secured against copy/read, once it power up it only brings a web browser directed to the local server web page and that's it.. no any other operation allowed by the normal user other than using browser and connecting to WiFi.

can it be done with windows/ ubuntu or any other distribution of linux ? **server folder and xampp** be given admin privileges and encrypted and auto run on system start-up even if admin does not log in (in case computer restart while i'm not @ office) and normal guest user can use computer as much as he want as long as he is not touching my xampp folder

This can also be useful for developers struggling to sell php applications without giving out source code

Comment: Since a dedicated server or raspberry pi would be running a linux distro its easy "apt-get install php5 apache2 mysql" and then upload your code into the web root don't give anyone the local username and password to the "server" and your sorted code secure

Comment: If you are going to host the web-service yourself on your own server, no one without direct access to the server will be able to get the source files. JS/Css is not possible to "protect" tho, cause they are always sent to the client.

Comment: And what will happen if system restarts ? Will it automatically run the server again or I will need to to login with admin first to re run it ?

Comment: I'm not worried about CSS or js its only the php and database that I need to keep safe

Comment: You can have applications running as a service and that way they will automatically start with a reboot. that way you don't need to re-enter your password every time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take into account that as soon as someone has direct access to the raspberry pi SD-Card he can easily get the root password as well as any password to your encryption solution as long as the password is saved on the card.

If you want to be really secure you need sort of dongle your sd card with the raspberry pi to make sure that the encryption can only be done if the sd card is entered in that specific pi and you need to encrypt the whole sd card.